# My proof on sum of two sequences is real number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ be real numbers. Show that their sum
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)$ is also a real number. Hint: you can use the triangle inequality.

This is what I came up with so far:

So lets say $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. Then if $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=y$ (where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, given in question) for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $N$ such that $|b_n-y|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N$.

We have $|a_n-x +b_n-y|<\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\geq N$.

Now with the triangle inequality $|x+y|\leq |x| + |y|$ that implies
$|a_n-x +b_n-y|\leq |a_n-x| + |b_n-y|$ so if we can make

$|a_n-x| + |b_n-y| <\varepsilon$ we know that $|a_n-x +b_n-y|$ is also smaller then $\varepsilon$.

but I dont know how to conclude the proof, that this sum is also a real number. I can make both terms on the right $\varepsilon/2$, but is this proof that their sum is also a real number?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Notice that you're not looking for a sum, but for the _limit_ of a sum. What have you already proven about  this limit?

Comment: that it exists?

Comment: I am confused. Are you asking why $x+y$ is a real number?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214225/my-proof-that-sum-of-convergent-sequences-converges-to-sum-of-limits?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My proof that sum of convergent sequences converges to sum of limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214225/my-proof-that-sum-of-convergent-sequences-converges-to-sum-of-limits)

Answer (score 1):

You're very much on the right track, but some corrections are needed. For example, you can say that

> We have $|a_n−x+b_n−y|<\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\geq N$.

No, we don't have that — this is what we need to prove, not what we know.

> So lets say $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n−x|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N$. Then if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=y$ (…) for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $N$ such that $|b_n−y|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N$.

While both statements are correct if stated separately, once you put them together, it doesn't look right. Using the same "$N$" gives an impression that it is the same number, while it doesn't have to be, i.e. not immediately from the definition. So you have to take care of this little issue, for example like that:

Assume $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N_a$ such that $|a_n−x|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N_a$. Assume $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=y$. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $N_b$ such that $|b_n−y|<\varepsilon$ for every $n\geq N_b$. Now let $N=\max\{N_a,N_b\}$.

> I can make both terms on the right $\varepsilon/2$.

This is an excellent idea! Yes, in the paragraph above you should replace each $\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon/2$. Since the definition is true for any number greater than zero, this number can certainly be $\varepsilon/2$.

If you apply this corrections, then you should have a valid proof of the desired claim. To make it more clear, you can start with stating your claim, like this:

Assume $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=y$. Let's show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=x+y$.

Comment: But I can say that x+y implies that I an-x I + I bn-y I<epsilon and if I can show that these two are smaller then epsilon, I can use the triangle inequality to show that                                          I an-x + bn-y I<epsilon and then this implies that the limit of the sum is also a real number because I can make the limit of the sum smaller then epsilon for any n>N or equal to N

Comment: @JamesOlivierbv: Again, correct idea, but poor presentation. If you start with $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon$ and $|b_n-y|<\varepsilon$, then you can **NOT** prove that $|a_n-x+b_n-y|<\varepsilon$, simply because it's not necessarily true. For example, if $a_n-x=0.9\varepsilon$, so it satisfies $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon$, and $b_n-y=0.8\varepsilon$, so it satisfies $|b_n-y|<\varepsilon$, then we'll have $|a_n-x+b_n-y|=|0.9\varepsilon+0.8\varepsilon|=1.7\varepsilon\not<\varepsilon$.

Comment: how should I present it then? wait, I can say, make an-x smaller then epsilon/2 and            bn-y also smaller then epsilon/2. Because the limit of an and bn is a real number, I can also make I an-x I < epsilon/2 and with bn the same

Comment: @JamesOlivierbv: (continued) And in general, from $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon$ and $|b_n-y|<\varepsilon$, by the triangle inequality we can only deduce that $|a_n-x+b_n-y|\leq|a_n-x|+|b_n-y|<\varepsilon+\varepsilon=2\varepsilon$, and that's the best we can do. That's why we wanna start with $\varepsilon/2$: pick an $\varepsilon>0$; apply the definition to find indices $N_a$ and $N_b$ such that $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon/2$ and $|b_n-y|<\varepsilon/2$ for all ... (as shown in my answer); and then apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: so if I an-x I + I bn-y I < epsilon/2 + epsilon/2<epsilon                   and using the triangle inequality then I an-x +bn-y I is also smaller then epsilon, meaning that there is a N such that the limit of the sum of the sequences also goes to some real number, and                 I an-x + bn-yI< epsilon means the limit of the sum of the sequences so this concludes it right?